# Using eclipse comparator from command line

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Can Eclipse Compare tool be called from command line? I just want to use it as a merge tool from an external tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware that you can do this out of the box. But you can download the RCP SDK and create a really stripped down version of Eclipse which contains just the compare plugin. That will also help greatly with the startup time.

Comment: Unluckly looks that this is true.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you insist on Eclipse for that? I've used [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) for exactly the same purpose (external diff tool). It has built in ability to be called from command-line.

Other options:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792910/best-graphical-source-code-diff-viewer-editor-for-code-comparison-and-merging

Comment: Even if we are getting offtopic: If you seriously want to compare stuff (and are on Windows), nothing beats BeyondCompare.

Comment: I just wanted to use the comparator I was used to. Anyway I've looked into alternatives. Thanks both.

Comment: I like and use others, but cross platform is a big win, as well as not  losing focus. I'm launching from unit test triggered from inside of eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the same thing so I wrote it: https://github.com/kgilmer/steb

From a shell, the following line will open a compare editor comparing f1.txt and f2.txt:

steb -c f1.txt f2.txt